# Context.ChangeTracker.Entries() throws an InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working on a .net web application with UnitOfWork Pattern guidelines and EntityFramework.

Context.ChangeTracker.Entries() method is throwing an InvalidOperatioException.

**Message**: "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker."

The code is too big and involves multiple layers, so can't paste the code here.

Since am using UnitOfWork Pattern, I am very much sure that I am working only on a single instance of the context. In which case do we get this error and is there any way I can figure out which entity is causing this problem?

Comment: *I am very much sure that I am working only on a single instance of the context* well, I've never seen a context with to change trackers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a dependency injector, then in your configuration ask your DI container or factory to create a single instance per request that way you are very sure its a single instance of DbContext that is created.

Comment: I am passing the unit of work to the service and the service works on context present inside unitOfWork, and the same unitOfWork is being passed to the subsequent layers/methods.

Comment: So what is responsible for creating instances of the entity framework dbcontext? clearly from the error message, some other instance is been created some where you may not be aware of since you have a huge code base and that is why you need a dependency injector if you dont have one